# I keep getting the `Set 'ethereum.autoRefreshOnNetworkChange' to 'false'` warning, despite setting value to false

Tags: metamask, web3-providers, ethers.js

I'm using `ethers.js` to connect to MetaMask. I keep seeing this warning in my console:

> inpage.js:1 MetaMask: MetaMask will soon stop reloading pages on
> network change. For more information, see:
> https://docs.metamask.io/guide/ethereum-provider.html#ethereum-autorefreshonnetworkchange
> Set 'ethereum.autoRefreshOnNetworkChange' to 'false' to silence this
> warning.

I tried setting the value to false immediately after detecting `window.ethereum` - but I'm still getting this warning. Here's my code:

```
    try {
      if(window.ethereum) {
        window.ethereum.autoRefreshOnNetworkChange = false;
        window.ethereum
          .on('accountsChanged', accounts => {
            window.location.reload();
          })
          .on('chainChanged', () => {
            window.location.reload();
          });
        await window.ethereum.request({method: 'eth_requestAccounts'});
        //...do stuff
      }
      else {
        throw new Error('Cannot connect to MetaMask or other Web3 wallet');
      }
    }
    catch(err) {
      throw err;
    }
```

Am I putting the value in the wrong place? I tried moving that line around, and nope.

Answer (score 0):

You might be accessing the said value even when it is undefined . Note by default it is "undefined" and not "true" or "false" .
So put a check that whether it is even defined or not , before assigning any value to it .

```
if (typeof window.ethereum.autoRefreshOnNetworkChange !== "undefined") {
    window.ethereum.autoRefreshOnNetworkChange = false;
  }
```

I used the above code in my method and it worked perfectly .